# How to access FormArray inside another FormArray

Tags: angular, types

I have a FormArray that contains another FormArray which I need to access in order to insert FormGroups, and print their content in an NgFor:

```
this.facturaForm = this.fb.group({
      articles: this.fb.array([
          this.fb.group({
            codigoMedida: ['', Validators.required],
            cantidad: ['', Validators.required],
            nombre: ['', Validators.required],
            precioUnidad: ['', Validators.required],
            precioRealUnidad: ['', Validators.required],
            precioTotal: ['', Validators.required],
            nota: ['', Validators.required],
            descripcion: ['', Validators.required],
  
            discounts: this.fb.array([
              this.fb.group({
                razon: ['', Validators.required],
                codigoDescuento: ['', Validators.required],
                porcentaje: ['', Validators.required],
                baseImponible: ['', Validators.required],
                importe: ['', Validators.required],
              })
            ]),
  
            charges: this.fb.array([
              this.fb.group({
                razon: ['1', Validators.required],
                porcentaje: ['', Validators.required],
                baseImponible: ['', Validators.required],
                importe: ['', Validators.required],
              }),
            ]),
  
            taxes: this.fb.array([
              this.fb.group({
                importe: ['', Validators.required],
                codigoMedida: ['', Validators.required],
                tipoImpuesto: ['', Validators.required],
                porcentaje: ['', Validators.required],
                porUnidad: ['', Validators.required],
                precioPorUnidad: ['', Validators.required],
                baseImponible: ['', Validators.required],
                cantidadPorUnidad: ['', Validators.required],
              })
            ]),
          })
      ]),
```

I have a getter that stores the content of the FormArray items, but I can't find a way to access the content of the FormArrays: Charges, Taxes, Discounts:

```
get articles(){
    return this.facturaForm.get('articles') as FormArray;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `at` to find the indexed article record, then call `get` to retrieve the `charges` property. For example:

```
   return this.facturaForm.get('articles').at(0).get('charges') as FormArray;
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot.